# Reindexing after initial download of bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core

I recently downloaded bitcoin core. Took about 1+ week to download 80%. One day I checked, it got an error message. When I closed and reopened the bitcoin core, it started reindexing. Any idea how long this will take? Turned it off after a day of "calculating indexing time". Was trying to mine low to no fee transactions as I start getting into bitcoin.

[image]

```
2017-10-18 05:36:19 receive version message: /Satoshi:0.15.0.1/: version 70015, blocks=490420, us=71.202.75.20:62505, peer=1908
2017-10-18 05:37:32 Pre-allocating up to position 0x6000000 in blk00622.dat
2017-10-18 05:37:45 receive version message: /Satoshi:0.13.1/: version 70014, blocks=490420, us=71.202.75.20:62519, peer=1909
2017-10-18 05:39:29 Pre-allocating up to position 0x7000000 in blk00622.dat
2017-10-18 05:40:07 socket send error An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  (10054)
2017-10-18 05:40:37 receive version message: /Satoshi:0.14.2/: version 70015, blocks=490420, us=71.202.75.20:62551, peer=1910
2017-10-18 05:41:03 Pre-allocating up to position 0x8000000 in blk00622.dat
2017-10-18 05:41:44 ProcessMessages(version, 113 bytes) FAILED peer=1911
```

Comment: "Was trying to mine low to no fee transactions as I start getting into bitcoin.": I am not really clear what you mean by that, but I suspect that it isn't possible.

Comment: What is in debug.log?

Comment: Where is the log located? Looking at my directory, I don't see this file. Trying to add a pic of the folder but not sure how on this reply.

Comment: Actually, edited the original question to add the picture here.

Comment: The debug.log file is located in the data directory which is not the same location as the install directory. In Window,s the default is `%APPDATA%/Bitcoin`

Comment: Ah, it's on my external drive. Using wireless external drive due to size of the blockchain now. There appears to be an error very early in the log. Can you guys take a look? There are few other failed messages after but I think this is the right one.

Comment: Also, does the error log contain any sensitive data?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured this one out. Running a full node on my other computer with internal hard drive is much quicker.

Believe the original problem that I had was that I downloaded the application on my internal hard drive but saved the blockchain itself on an wireless external drive. Having the external drive disconnected even once I think would cause some issue.

Given the size of the blockchain, not sure what the plan is once it reaches 1TB?